# How to select multiple columns in a RDD with Spark (pySpark)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say I have a RDD that has comma delimited data. Each comma delimited value represents the amount of hours slept in the day of a week.

So for i.e. [8,7,6,7,8,8,5]

How can I manipulate the RDD so it only has Monday, Wednesday, Friday values? There are no column names by the way. But the PySpark platform seems to have _co1,_co2,...,_coN as columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont know which version you are using but I recommend `DataFrame`s since most of upgrades are coming for `DataFrame`s. (I prefer spark 2.3.2)

First convert `rdd` to `DataFrame`:

```
df = rdd.toDF(["M","Tu","W","Th","F","Sa","Su"])
```

Then select days you want to work with:

```
df.select("M","W","F").show(3)
```

Or directly use `map` with `lambda`:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: [x[i] for i in [0,2,4])
```

Hope it helps!